# How to check if certain extjs panel is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have to add add a javascript code after certain panel is loaded (I have to use panel ID). How can I check this that panel is rendered and now I can access its id by using document.getElementbyId.
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consult the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-event-afterrender).

For each of your questions:

1. You can one of the many events exposed. There is an [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-event-afterrender) event.
2. You set the `id` of the panel accordingly. All components have this id property as a result of inheritance from `AbstractComponent`, see the [docs on this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-id).

This is the code:

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {  
    id : 'thisIsYourId', //<<set this
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
myPanel.on("afterrender", function() {  
    //this code will run after the panel renders.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var cmp = Ext.getCmp('<panel-id>');
if(cmp){
    //panel exists
    if(cmp.rendered){
        //panel is rendered
    }
}
```